# Are my quantified statements translated from English correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

There exists a real number between any two sequential natural numbers.

$$(\exists x \in \Bbb {R})( \forall a,b \in \Bbb {N}) a < b, b > x > a$$

If an integer is positive, it equals its absolute value

(∀xℤ+)[x=|x|]

Comment: Your first is wrong.  You wrote there is a real number that is between any pair of natural numbers $a<b$.  You meant to write that between any pair of natural numbers $a<b$ there is a real number.  The real number could be different for different natural numbers.  In your second, you left out $\in$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh I see. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement is incorrect - it gives one $x$ for all $a, b \in\mathbb{N}$. You need exchange positions of quantifiers i.e.
$$( \forall a,b \in \Bbb {N}, a < b)(\exists x \in \Bbb {R})( b > x > a)$$

Comment: Constructive critique is welcome, especially in correct answer case, of course, if dumb down voter have something to say.